# How to combine equations and graphical calculus in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

I am writing an article about category theory and a lot of my equations are graphical, like this:

[image: Graphical calculus and equation]

Straight lines (and later, bent lines and circles) represent morphisms in an abelian category.

But it does not look good at all, especially the spacing.
You can see how the vertical spacing of the two sums is messed up and the placement of the equality signs is done quite arbitrarily by hand, with a mediocre result. The distance of the prefactor `\dim Y` to the line is too big. The placement of the line and node labels is done by TikZ, which looks decent.
Is there a good package or preferred method how to do all of this with an automatically good looking result?

My code is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[thick, dot/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=1pt}]
        %TODO Get vertical spacing of sums right
        \draw (0,0) -- node[right] {$X$} (0,3);
        \node at (1,1.5) {=};
        \newcommand{\inserted}[2]{\draw (#1,0) -- node[right] {$X$} +(0,1) node[dot] {} node[right] {$\iota$} -- node[right] {$#2$} +(0,2) node[dot] {} node[right] {$\iota^*$} -- node[right] {$X$} +(0,3);}
        \node at (1.9,1.5) {$\displaystyle\sum_{\iota \in \mathcal{C}(X,\Omega_\mathcal{C})}$};
        \inserted{2.8}{\Omega_\mathcal{C}}
        \node at (3.8,1.5) {=};
        \node at (5.0,1.5) {$\displaystyle\sum_{\mathclap{\substack{Y \in \Lambda_\mathcal{C} \\ \iota \in \mathcal{C}(X,Y)}}} \dim Y$};
        \inserted{6.2}{Y}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get correct baselines, by using the `baseline=(X.base)` key of TikZ. Now you can choose any node inside your tikzpicture, which should serve as baseline and name it `(X)`. To get this in a multiline equation, simply use one of the multiline `amsmath` environments, e.g. `align`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath,amssymb}
\tikzset{
    dot/.style = {
        draw,fill,
        circle,
        inner sep=0pt,
        outer sep=0pt,
        minimum size=2pt
    }
}
\newcommand\stikz[1]{\tikz[baseline=(X.base)]{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    \stikz{
        \draw (0,-1) -- (0,1);
        \node[right] (X) at (0,0) {$X$};
    }
    &=
    \stikz{\node (X) {$\displaystyle\sum_{\iota \in \mathcal{C}(X,\Omega_\mathcal{C})}$};}
    \stikz{
        \draw (0,-1) -- (0,1);
        \node[right] at (0,0.75) {$X$};
        \node[dot,label={right:$\iota^*$}] at (0,0.4) {};
        \node[right] (X) at (0,0) {$\Omega_\mathcal{C}$};
        \node[dot,label={right:$\iota$}] at (0,-0.4) {};
        \node[right] at (0,-0.75) {$X$};
    }
    =
    \stikz{\node (X) {$\displaystyle\sum_{\substack{Y \in \Lambda_\mathcal{C} \\ \iota \in \mathcal{C}(X,Y)}} \dim Y$};}
    \stikz{
        \draw (0,-1) -- (0,1);
        \node[right] at (0,0.75) {$X$};
        \node[dot,label={right:$\iota^*$}] at (0,0.4) {};
        \node[right] (X) at (0,0) {$Y$};
        \node[dot,label={right:$\iota$}] at (0,-0.4) {};
        \node[right] at (0,-0.75) {$X$};
    }
\\
    \stikz{
        \draw (0,-1) -- (0,1);
        \node[right] (X) at (0,0) {$Y$};
    }
    &=
    \stikz{\node (X) {$\displaystyle\sum_{\kappa \in \mathcal{C}(Y,\Gamma_\mathcal{C})}$};}
    \stikz{
        \draw (0,-1) -- (0,1);
        \node[right] at (0,0.75) {$Y$};
        \node[dot,label={right:$\kappa^*$}] at (0,0.4) {};
        \node[right] (X) at (0,0) {$\Gamma_\mathcal{C}$};
        \node[dot,label={right:$\kappa$}] at (0,-0.4) {};
        \node[right] at (0,-0.75) {$Y$};
    }
    =
    \stikz{\node (X) {$\displaystyle\sum_{\substack{Y \in \Phi_\mathcal{C} \\ \kappa \in \mathcal{C}(Y,Z)}} \dim Z$};}
    \stikz{
        \draw (0,-1) -- (0,1);
        \node[right] at (0,0.75) {$Y$};
        \node[dot,label={right:$\kappa^*$}] at (0,0.4) {};
        \node[right] (X) at (0,0) {$Z$};
        \node[dot,label={right:$\kappa$}] at (0,-0.4) {};
        \node[right] at (0,-0.75) {$Y$};
    }
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Good idea to use the native spacing of (La)TeX.

Comment: What do I do if I want to write such an equation over several lines? Inserting an `\\` doesn't help, and if I have two newlines in an `equation` environment, it complains.

Comment: I meant "inserting an \\ doesn't help", but stackexchange doesn't allow me to edit anymore.

Comment: @Turion See my updated answer.