# How do I horizontally align equations with graphical calculus?

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, align

I have a graphical proof in category theory that I wrote with TikZ and the align environment (Thanks to Henri's answer in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155796/how-to-combine-equations-and-graphical-calculus-in-tikz)). The diagrams on each line have a recurring feature, a vertical line labelled with "A". I would like these lines to be horizontally aligned.

[image: Graphical calculus]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{knots}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

    \tikzset{dot/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=1pt},diagram/.style={knot=black,thick}}
    \newcommand{\tikzb}[1]{\tikz[baseline=(B.base)]{#1}}
    \newcommand{\qdim}[1]{\left<#1\right>}
    \newcommand{\Aid}{\draw[diagram] (0,-1.5) -- node[right] (B) {A} (0,1.5);}
    \newcommand{\braket}[2]{\left< #1 \vphantom{#2} \right|\left. \vphantom{#1} #2 \right>}
    \pgfkeys{/encircle/.cd,label/.initial=$\Omega_{\mathcal{C}}$,angle/.initial=20}
    \newcommand{\encircle}[2][]{%
        \pgfkeys{/encircle/.cd,#1}
        \draw[diagram] (1,0) arc (0:\pgfkeysvalueof{/encircle/angle}:1 and 0.4) node[above] {\pgfkeysvalueof{/encircle/label}} arc (\pgfkeysvalueof{/encircle/angle}:180:1 and 0.4);
        #2
        \draw[diagram] (-1,0) arc (-180:0:1 and 0.4);
    }

    \begin{align}
        & & \tikzb{\draw[diagram] (0,-1.5) -- node[right] (B) {X} (0,1.5);}
        \tikzb{\encircle{\Aid}}\\
        & = \sum_{Y \in \Lambda_\mathcal{C}} \qdim{Y}
        & \tikzb{\draw[diagram] (0,-1.5) -- node[right] (B) {X} (0,1.5);}
        \tikzb{\encircle[label=Y]{\Aid}}
        & \qquad \text{By the definition of $\Omega_{\mathcal{C}}$} \\
        & = \sum_{\mathclap{\substack{Y \in \Lambda_\mathcal{C} \\ Z \in \Lambda_\mathcal{C} \\ \iota_i \in \mathcal{C}(Z, X \otimes Y) \\ \braket{\iota_i}{\iota_j} = \delta_{i,j}}}} \qdim{Y}\qdim{Z}
        & \tikzb{
            \draw[diagram] (-1,-1.5) to[out=90, in=245] node[left] {X} (-0.7,-0.3) coordinate[dot,label={right:$\iota_i^*$}] (A) to node[left] (B) {Z} (-0.7,0.3) coordinate[dot,label={right:$\iota_i$}] (C) to[out=115,in=270] (-1,1.5);
            \draw[diagram] (1,0) to[out=90,in=65] (C);
            \Aid
            \draw[diagram] (A) to[out=295,in=270] (1,0) node[right] {Y};
        }
        & \qquad \text{Insertion of a further $\Omega_{\mathcal{C}}$}
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

You don't need the `knots` tikz library necessarily to compile this code. I tried adding &'s in the tikz code, to no avail.

Comment: I would consider the Tikz bits to be images, and use a tabular, rather than considering them to be maths and try to `align` them.  Could that be a suitable approach?

Comment: I have sums as well, that's the reason I wanted a maths environment. In principle I could work around having a tabular, though. But that doesn't really help since I want to align by a feature of the image, I don't see how this is easier in a tabular.

Comment: Aligning by a *feature of* the image is awkward - I think you'll need an expert rather than my suggestion. However: a coordinate node as the left-most item in your drawing, positioned relative to the feature to which you would like to align, might just do it - with or without a tabular.

Comment: It makes sense if you look at the images. I'll think about your suggestion with the coordinate node, that sounds like a good workaround at least.

Comment: Adding a coordinate doesn't help. For some reason, an empty node works.

Comment: @ChrisH, do post it as your answer, otherwise I'll post it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this is more of a workaround, but I would consider the Tikz bits to be images.  Then I'd put everything in a tabular to get everything into tidy columns.

Aligning by a feature of the image is awkward, however, but a reliable manual way would be to add an empty node as the left-most item in your drawing, positioned relative to the feature to which you would like to align.  This could then be left-aligned in a tabular column, and it could even work in an align.

By positioning the alignment node vertically as well you could match the baselines nicely as well if needed.

**Edit: example is ready -- but note that I've used manual positioning of the empty node I'm using as a left stop, just because I found it easier in adapting the original**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{knots}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

    \tikzset{dot/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=1pt},diagram/.style={knot=black,thick}}
    \newcommand{\tikzb}[1]{\tikz[baseline=(B.base)]{#1}}
    \newcommand{\qdim}[1]{\left<#1\right>}
    \newcommand{\Aid}{\draw[diagram] (0,-1.5) -- node[right] (B) {A} (0,1.5);}
    \newcommand{\braket}[2]{\left< #1 \vphantom{#2} \right|\left. \vphantom{#1} #2 \right>}
    \pgfkeys{/encircle/.cd,label/.initial=$\Omega_{\mathcal{C}}$,angle/.initial=20}
    \newcommand{\encircle}[2][]{%
        \pgfkeys{/encircle/.cd,#1}
        \draw[diagram] (1,0) arc (0:\pgfkeysvalueof{/encircle/angle}:1 and 0.4) node[above] {\pgfkeysvalueof{/encircle/label}} arc (\pgfkeysvalueof{/encircle/angle}:180:1 and 0.4);
        #2
        \draw[diagram] (-1,0) arc (-180:0:1 and 0.4);
    }

    \begin{tabular}{lll}
         & \tikzb{\draw[diagram] (0,-1.5) -- node[right] (B) {X} (0,1.5);}
        \tikzb{\encircle{\Aid}}\\
          $\displaystyle=\sum_{Y \in \Lambda_\mathcal{C}} \qdim{Y}$
        & \tikzb{\draw[diagram] (0,-1.5) -- node[right] (B) {X} (0,1.5);}
        \tikzb{\encircle[label=Y]{\Aid}}
        & By the definition of $\Omega_{\mathcal{C}}$ \\
         $\displaystyle=\sum_{\mathclap{\substack{Y \in \Lambda_\mathcal{C} \\ Z \in \Lambda_\mathcal{C} \\ \iota_i \in \mathcal{C}(Z, X \otimes Y) \\ \braket{\iota_i}{\iota_j} = \delta_{i,j}}}} \qdim{Y}\qdim{Z}$
        & \tikzb{
            \draw[diagram] (-1,-1.5) to[out=90, in=245] node[left] {X} (-0.7,-0.3) coordinate[dot,label={right:$\iota_i^*$}] (A) to node[left] (B) {Z} (-0.7,0.3) coordinate[dot,label={right:$\iota_i$}] (C) to[out=115,in=270] (-1,1.5);
            \draw[diagram] (1,0) to[out=90,in=65] (C);
            \Aid
            \draw[diagram] (A) to[out=295,in=270] (1,0) node[right] {Y};
            \node[draw=none,fill=none]   at (-1.6,0) {};%this node is a left stop.
        }
        & Insertion of a further $\Omega_{\mathcal{C}}$
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of above code]

Comment: I disagree about the tabular. With align and the empty node on the right hand side, you get a similar result. (That's what I'm doing now) Also, you don't need to give the empty node any parameters. Apart from that, great.

Comment: Wait, so you're only adding an empty node to one of the pictures?

Comment: @Turion in the end yes, when I wrote the text my intention was to position it relative to the line labelled A in all the diagrams

Answer (score 2):

I just added some kerning after two of the images.  Of course, this requires manual intervention.

```
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

    \tikzset{dot/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=1pt},diagram/.style={knot=black,thick}}
    \newcommand{\tikzb}[1]{\tikz[baseline=(B.base)]{#1}}
    \newcommand{\qdim}[1]{\left<#1\right>}
    \newcommand{\Aid}{\draw[diagram] (0,-1.5) -- node[right] (B) {A} (0,1.5);}
    \newcommand{\braket}[2]{\left< #1 \vphantom{#2} \right|\left. \vphantom{#1} #2 \right>}
    \pgfkeys{/encircle/.cd,label/.initial=$\Omega_{\mathcal{C}}$,angle/.initial=20}
    \newcommand{\encircle}[2][]{%
        \pgfkeys{/encircle/.cd,#1}
        \draw[diagram] (1,0) arc (0:\pgfkeysvalueof{/encircle/angle}:1 and 0.4) node[above] {\pgfkeysvalueof{/encircle/label}} arc (\pgfkeysvalueof{/encircle/angle}:180:1 and 0.4);
        #2
        \draw[diagram] (-1,0) arc (-180:0:1 and 0.4);
    }

    \begin{align}
        & & \tikzb{\draw[diagram] (0,-1.5) -- node[right] (B) {X} (0,1.5);}
        \tikzb{\encircle{\Aid}}\mkern12mu\\
        & = \sum_{Y \in \Lambda_\mathcal{C}} \qdim{Y}
        & \tikzb{\draw[diagram] (0,-1.5) -- node[right] (B) {X} (0,1.5);}
        \tikzb{\encircle[label=Y]{\Aid}}\mkern16.5mu
        & \qquad \text{By the definition of $\Omega_{\mathcal{C}}$} \\
        & = \sum_{\mathclap{\substack{Y \in \Lambda_\mathcal{C} \\ Z \in \Lambda_\mathcal{C} \\ \iota_i \in \mathcal{C}(Z, X \otimes Y) \\ \braket{\iota_i}{\iota_j} = \delta_{i,j}}}} \qdim{Y}\qdim{Z}
        & \tikzb{
            \draw[diagram] (-1,-1.5) to[out=90, in=245] node[left] {X} (-0.7,-0.3) coordinate[dot,label={right:$\iota_i^*$}] (A) to node[left] (B) {Z} (-0.7,0.3) coordinate[dot,label={right:$\iota_i$}] (C) to[out=115,in=270] (-1,1.5);
            \draw[diagram] (1,0) to[out=90,in=65] (C);
            \Aid
            \draw[diagram] (A) to[out=295,in=270] (1,0) node[right] {Y};
        }
        & \qquad \text{Insertion of a further $\Omega_{\mathcal{C}}$}
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's hard to deal with if I want to enlarge the  proof lader. Requires too much manual intervention and fiddling around.

Comment: @Turion  Indeed, manual re-alignment is a path of last resort.

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness, I'll add my own solution based on Chris H's suggestions. It adds an empty node at the same coordinates in every image. The coordinate system is aligned to have A in the origin, so if this node is the rightmost element of the image, it is the border that the image is being aligned to. That way, only one coordinate needs to be manually tuned in order to align all of the images at the same point. This is especially important for me since the actual proof covers the whole page, so I don't want to fiddle around with every single image.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{knots}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

    \tikzset{dot/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=1pt},diagram/.style={knot=black,thick}}
    \newcommand{\tikzb}[1]{\tikz[baseline=(B.base)]{#1}}
    \newcommand{\qdim}[1]{\left<#1\right>}
    \newcommand{\braket}[2]{\left< #1 \vphantom{#2} \right|\left. \vphantom{#1} #2 \right>}
    \pgfkeys{/encircle/.cd,label/.initial=$\Omega_{\mathcal{C}}$,angle/.initial=20}
    \newcommand{\encircle}[2][]{%
        \pgfkeys{/encircle/.cd,#1}
        \draw[diagram] (1,0) arc (0:\pgfkeysvalueof{/encircle/angle}:1 and 0.4) node[above] {\pgfkeysvalueof{/encircle/label}} arc (\pgfkeysvalueof{/encircle/angle}:180:1 and 0.4);
        #2
        \draw[diagram] (-1,0) arc (-180:0:1 and 0.4);
    }

    \newcommand{\tikzoffset}{\node at (1.63,0) {};}
    \newcommand{\Aid}{\draw[diagram] (0,-1.5) -- node[right] (B) {A} (0,1.5); \tikzoffset}

    \begin{align}
        & & \tikzb{
            \draw[diagram] (-1.2,-1.5) -- node[left] (B) {X} (-1.2,1.5);
            \encircle{\Aid}
        }\\
        & = \sum_{\mathclap{Y \in \Lambda_\mathcal{C}}} \qdim{Y}
        & \tikzb{
            \draw[diagram] (-1.2,-1.5) -- node[left] (B) {X} (-1.2,1.5);
            \encircle[label=Y]{\Aid}
        }
        & \qquad \text{By the definition of $\Omega_{\mathcal{C}}$} \\
        & = \sum_{\mathclap{\substack{Y, Z \in \Lambda_\mathcal{C} \\ \iota_i \in \mathcal{C}(Z, X \otimes Y^*) \\ \braket{\iota_i}{\iota_j} = \delta_{i,j}}}} \qdim{Y}\qdim{Z}
        & \tikzb{
            \draw[diagram] (-1.2,-1.5) to[out=90, in=245] node[left] {X} (-0.7,-0.3) coordinate[dot,label={right:$\iota_i^*$}] (A) to node[left] (B) {Z} (-0.7,0.3) coordinate[dot,label={right:$\iota_i$}] (C) to[out=115,in=270] node[left] {X} (-1.2,1.5);
            \draw[diagram] (1,0) to[out=90,in=65] (C);
            \Aid
            \draw[diagram] (A) to[out=295,in=270] (1,0) node[right] {Y};
        }
        & \qquad \text{Insertion of a further $\Omega_{\mathcal{C}}$}
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

I also improved/corrected some other details meanwhile.

[image]

Comment: Actually, one needs to put all the node names in dollar signs as well!